# a correct way of forcing assembly load into current domain

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project that uses several class libraries that are part of my project, first AssemblyA is loaded, then AssemblyB is loaded. In AssemblyA there is code that does the following

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
var assemblyB = assemblies
                .Where(x=>x.GetName() == "AssemblyB")
                .First();
var type = assemblyB.GetType("AssemblyB_Type");
```

Unfortunately when AssemblyA tries to do that, AssemblyB is not loaded yet into CurrentDomain, so to load that assembly I'm doing the following unnecessary thing:

```
var x = typeof(AssemblyB.AssemblyB_Type);
```

The compiler shows warning that this line is not needed, though I can't find words to explain it that otherwise it won't work, so the question would be, how do you correctly (in Feng Shui terms) force Assembly load into CurrentDomain without doing extra-unuseful plumbing

Comment: If you want to load an assembly on demand then just use Assembly.Load().  Or use var type = typeof(NamespaceNameInAssemblyB.AssemblyB_Type) to let the CLR load the assembly automatically.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused.  If you are able to do typeof(AssemblyB.AssemblyB_Type), then why do you need to do assemblyB.GetType("AssemblyB_Type")?

Comment: There's a 3rd party JInt library (JavaScript interpriter). It allows binding CLR types from within JavaScript source. First it uses AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() and then it tries to locate the appropriate type in that assembly, if my assembly wasn't touched by C# code, it is not loaded to CurrentDomain and is not accessible from JavaScript...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your existing code is the best way to do that (AFAIK).

To get rid of the warning, change it to

```
typeof(AssemblyB.AssemblyB_Type).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

If your referenced assemblies are deployed correctly, they should "just load" if you call one of its types. The .NET framework should take care of this for you.

Here's a good article explaining the way the framework searches for your referenced assemblies: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.71).aspx

I'm curious what you're doing that you need to load an assembly prematurely like this?

A hack to answer your direct question is to use Assembly.Load(string location) - though I would discourage this unless absolutely necessary. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx

Comment: There's a 3rd party JInt library (JavaScript interpriter). It allows binding CLR types from within JavaScript source. First it uses `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and then it tries to locate the appropriate type in that assembly, if my assembly wasn't touched by C# code, it is not loaded to CurrentDomain and is not accessible from JavaScript...

Comment: Gotcha. Nothing jumps off my head atm - A nice dynamic way to fix this would be to enumerate AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(), and loading all the assemblies those ones reference. This could cause memory and startup performance issues - but I think it should be OK. See "Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getreferencedassemblies.aspx

Comment: Something feels weird here though, I think there's a better solution but it may involve changes to JInt....

Comment: Also, Lu4, make sure to select an answer if you decide to go on way or another!

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies won't help. The refernces are being removed, oops sorry, 'optimized' at compile time. As far as I can tell there's no way to disable this optimization.

Comment: Hey FerretallicA, 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()' only assemblies that are currently loaded into the domain, not necessarily those assemblies that are referenced by your DLL. Yes, it is definitely an optimization. If you have a question about this stuff, I would recommend starting a new question!

Answer (score 1):

So, you could just load all the assemblies in your bin directory into the app domain.  This should solve your problem.

```
var assemblies = Directory.GetFiles(containingDirectory, "*.dll")'

foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
{
    Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assembly));
}
```

Comment: This only works when you make assumptions about where it is being run from. For example, it will not work when your code is running in a different host such as IIS or a unit test runner.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
   public static void EnsureAssemblyLoads(this Type pType) {
      // do nothing
   }
}

...

typeof(SomeType).EnsureAssemblyLoads();
```